# Changing attribute binding to third party directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am trying to change the attribute that is passed in to the third party directive `md-icon`.
I tried by delegating, but the value does not change.

So far this is what I have.

```
angular.module('app').decorator('mdIconDirective', function ($delegate) {
let directive = $delegate[0];
let compile = directive.compile;

directive.compile = function(el, attrs) {
    let link = compile.apply(this, arguments);

    return function(scope, el, attrs) {
        let src = `node_modules/@mdi/svg/svg/${attrs.mdSvgSrc}.svg`;
        el[0].setAttribute('mdSvgSrc', src);

        link.apply(this, arguments)
    };
};

return $delegate;
});
```

I want to change the value passed in `md-svg-src` so that I don't have to write the full path every time.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the value passed in `md-svg-src` so that I don't have to write the full path every time.

You may not want to make separate HTTP requests for every icon, so you can bundle your SVG icons together and pre-load them with `$mdIconProvider` as an icon set. An icon set can also be given a name, which acts as a namespace for individual icons, so you can reference them like `"social:cake"`.

```
app.config(function($mdIconProvider) {
    $mdIconProvider
      .iconSet('social', 'img/icons/sets/social-icons.svg', 24)
      .defaultIconSet('node_modules/@mdi/svg/svg/core-icons.svg', 24);
});
```

This technique can be used to avoid using the full path each time.

```
<md-icon md-svg-icon="social:android" aria-label="android "></md-icon>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Material `md-icon` Directive API Reference](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdIcon)
- [Material Design Icon Guide — Self-Hosting](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#setup-method-2-self-hosting)

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but I really need to know how to manupulate an attribute binding before it's sent to the 3rd party directive. Thanks